# How to regenerate Build Gradle: Module app file

Tags: android, gradle

I was working in my Android project, my computer shut off while working with my project when power off. I recently tried to build my project but I couldn't because my Build Gradle : Module app file was corrupt and someone it had another's XML layout code, so I lost all the content of the module app file. How can I regenerate it?

**NOTE**
I tried to view the local history, unfortunately, I don't have any right structured file as before available on it.

If I would need to make it from scratch, how do I know the structure? (What does it need to have, an specific order and values).

Comment: create a new android studio project and take that gradle file as reference

Comment: I think it'll work if use rebuild project from the main menu. Once try this.

Comment: Or, make a new empty project and copy/paste the gradle configs. This might also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the `build.gradle` file in the Project tool window and select `Local History > Show History`. You can revert to any saved changes if they exist.

Alternatively, you can delete the corrupted file and start from scratch:

1. Switch to Project view in the Project tool window
2. Right-click on the root folder of your module and select `New > File`
3. Name it 'build.gradle'
4. Modify this file as needed (add plugins, defaultConfig, dependencies, etc).

You can use an uncorrupted `build.gradle` file as reference by creating a new (temporary) Android Studio project and adding a new module to it. Now you have a fresh `build.gradle` file. From there, it's a matter of adding dependencies and making any other modifications so your code compiles.

As of this writing, the general structure of the `build.gradle` file for an android library is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // module dependencies
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what kind of file should I make, when I select the option to create a new file, it appears a menu with different file options but I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: Also, I can't name the file as "build.gradle" because it exist another one called like that: the build.Gradle "myappname".

Comment: You would have to delete the corrupted one first. `New > File` creates a generic file. When it prompts you for the name, enter `build.gradle`. It might benefit you to create a new project and copy all your source files over. It'll be a valuable experience for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there local history available ?**

Try right clicking the faulty gradle file / XML file / Java file  and checking Local History -> Show History

If you can fetch the local history, right click the history entry and click revert

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this doesn't seems to work for me, the local history only saves from a range of 12 hours, this happened yesterday, so it already passed more than 12 hours :/

Comment: oh really , my local history keep file more than that , im sorry for you :/